# how to remove last comma ' , ' with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

how to remove last comma ' , ' with jquery. Below is my code jquery for slideshow image background ,php code will loop image url in javascript, mean user can change image in admin :

```
                navigation              :   1,      //Slideshow controls on/off
                thumbnail_navigation    :   1,      //Thumbnail navigation
                slide_counter           :   1,      //Display slide numbers
                slide_captions          :   1,      //Slide caption (Pull from "title" in slides array)
                slides                  :   [       //Slideshow Images
                                                <?php    // this will looping  image background custom - xx_rusly_xx
                                                    $images = getFieldOrder('background_slideshow_image');
                                                        foreach($images as $image){
                                                            echo "{image : '";
                                                            echo get('background_slideshow_image',1,$image);
                                                            echo "'},";
                                                        } 
                                                ?>
                                            ]                           
            }); 
        });

    </script>
```

If u see i put some php code for loop image url

```
<?php    // this will looping  image background custom - xx_rusly_xx
$images = getFieldOrder('background_slideshow_image');
    foreach($images as $image){
        echo "{image : '";
        echo get('background_slideshow_image',1,$image);
        echo "'},";
    } 
?>
```

and browser will generate javascript with php like this :

```
//Components
        navigation              :   1,      //Slideshow controls on/off
        thumbnail_navigation    :   1,      //Thumbnail navigation
        slide_counter           :   1,      //Display slide numbers
        slide_captions          :   1,      //Slide caption (Pull from "title" in slides array)
        slides                  :   [       //Slideshow Images
        {image : 'http://iconcept-project.com/dev/gd/wp-content/files_mf/1.jpg'},
        {image : 'http://iconcept-project.com/dev/gd/wp-content/files_mf/2.jpg'},
        {image : 'http://iconcept-project.com/dev/gd/wp-content/files_mf/3.jpg'},
        {image : 'http://iconcept-project.com/dev/gd/wp-content/files_mf/4.jpg'},                                                                                                                   ]                           
    }); 
});         
</script>
```

and the problem is how to remove comma in last line, because with internet explorer this will not run except i remove the last comma.

```
{image : 'http://iconcept-project.com/dev/gd/wp-content/files_mf/4.jpg'},
```

here is full code --> http://pastebin.com/c1A7ZKGr

thanks for help.

Comment: What does the rendered html look like 'view source'?

Comment: http://iconcept-project.com/dev/gd/

Comment: (Offtopic) P.S. try to optimize the images size. Loads too long

Comment: @Roko thanks for suggestion, site still in development phase :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious. Why don't you do that in PHP side?

```
<?php    // this will looping  image background custom - xx_rusly_xx
$images = getFieldOrder('background_slideshow_image');
    foreach($images as $ind => $image){
        echo "{image : '";
        echo get('background_slideshow_image',1,$image);
        echo "'}".($ind == count($images)-1 ? '' : ','); // no comma for last image
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in your js script but php script. Do it like this:

```
<?php    // this will looping  image background custom - xx_rusly_xx
$comma = false;
$images = getFieldOrder('background_slideshow_image');
    foreach($images as $image){
        if ($comma) echo ","; else $comma=true;
        echo "{image : '";
        echo get('background_slideshow_image',1,$image);
        echo "'}";
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since JSON evaluates as valid object literal in JavaScript, you should be using [`json_encode` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
<?php    
    $images = getFieldOrder('background_slideshow_image');
    $out = array();
    foreach($images as $image){
        $out[] = array('image' => get('background_slideshow_image',1,$image));
    } 
    echo json_encode($out);
?>
```

*(you'd have to remove the surrounding `[...]` in your code)*

Building literals and code manually with strings is doomed to fail (eventually).

Answer (score 1):

```
​var string = ​'kurec,kur,kureika,'​;
string.substr(0,string.length-1)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QVpWU/

Answer (score 1):

javascript :

```
s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1);
```

or use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php) instead of a home made function.

Answer (score 0):

You should control this in php.

```
   foreach($images as $i => $image){
        echo $i === 0 ? "" : ",";
        echo "{image : '";
        echo get('background_slideshow_image',1,$image);
        echo "'}";
    }
```